# Google Chrome по умолчанию Windows 10 bat file

Tags: google-chrome, cmd, windows-10, bat, powershell

Как можно сделать Google Chrome браузером по умолчанию в Windows 10 батником?

Пробовал через PowerShell командами

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\https\UserChoice' -Name ProgId -Value 'ChromeHTML'
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice' -Name ProgId -Value 'ChromeHTML'
```

Но не срабатывает. Хотя отрабатывает без ошибок

Так же пробовал

```
chrome.exe --make-default-browser
```

Тоже отрабатывает без ошибок, но не дает никакого результата.

Еще есть хотелка что бы при установке браузера сразу в нем было расширение AdBlock (но это второй вопрос)

Comment: Это читали? https://winaero.com/blog/prevent-windows-10-from-resetting-your-default-apps/

Comment: @ViktorTomilov тоесть в любом случае необходимо руками править в настройках? У меня около 100 машин, руками это печально(